# exception in thread main java.lang.illegalargumentexception. Training dataset /tmp/iris.csv can not be found in mahout

Tags: mahout, bigdata

When I try to work MLP in mahout:

```
/home/batu/Documents/mahout/trunk/bin/mahout org.apache.mahout.classifier.mlp.TrainMultilayerPerceptron -i /tmp/iris.csv -labels Iris-setosa Iris-versicolor Iris-virginica -mo /tmp/mlp.model -ls 4 8 3 -l 0.2 -m 0.35 -r 0.0001
```

this exception occurs.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.illegalargumentexception: Training dataset /tmp/iris2.csv cannot be found!
>   at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:115)
>   at org.apache.mahout.classifier.mlp.TrainMultiLayerPerceptron.main(TrainMultiLayerPerceptron.java:124)

[image: Exception and callstack]

Comment: Hi Batu, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Rather than showing a screenshot of your error, your question would be better if you copied and pasted the error in - or at least, a small snippet of the crucial part.  Questions are better with as much verbal description of the problem as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.When I try to work MLP in mahout: /home/batu/Documents/mahout/trunk/bin/mahout org.apache.mahout.classifier.mlp.TrainMultilayerPerceptron -i /tmp/iris.csv -labels Iris-setosa Iris-versicolor Iris-virginica -mo /tmp/mlp.model -ls 4 8 3 -l 0.2 -m 0.35 -r 0.0001 with this code i give an error like exception in thread main java.lang.illegalargumentexception. Training dataset /tmp/iris.csv can not be found in mahout. Please help me!!!!